# Unexpected collision behaviour when block moves fast - sprite passes through

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I have a square frame in which the user is allowed to move a block in but not touch the frame. If the user touches the square frame the game ends. Currently I have a problem where if the user swipes the block quickly, it passes through the frame without any collision/contact detections. If the player moves the block slowly and touches the frame then it detects a collision. My code is as follows and I cant get it to stop passing through the frame.

```
// setup play scene
let playScreen = SKSpriteNode(color: .clearColor(), size: CGSize(width: 370, height: 370))
playScreen.position = CGPoint(x: frame.midX, y: frame.midY - CGFloat(yFrame))
// create the rectangle which will represent physics body
let rect = CGRect(origin: CGPoint(x: -playScreen.size.width/2, y: -playScreen.size.height/2), size: playScreen.size)
// apply physics conditions to the play scene
playScreen.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(edgeLoopFromRect: rect)
playScreen.physicsBody!.friction = 0
// add play scene to the frame
addChild(playScreen)
playScreen.physicsBody!.categoryBitMask = BitMask.frame
playScreen.physicsBody!.contactTestBitMask = BitMask.player
playScreen.physicsBody!.collisionBitMask = BitMask.player
playScreen.physicsBody!.usesPreciseCollisionDetection = true;

// set up player block
player.position = CGPoint(x:frame.size.width/2, y: frame.size.height/2  - CGFloat(yFrame))
player.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: CGSize(width: 30, height: 30))
player.physicsBody!.dynamic = true
player.physicsBody!.friction = 0
player.physicsBody!.affectedByGravity = false
player.physicsBody!.allowsRotation = false
addChild(player)
player.physicsBody!.categoryBitMask     = BitMask.player
player.physicsBody!.contactTestBitMask  = BitMask.obstacle | BitMask.frame
player.physicsBody!.collisionBitMask    = BitMask.obstacle | BitMask.frame
```

I have the following contact detection:

```
func didBeginContact(contact: SKPhysicsContact) {
    var firstBody: SKPhysicsBody
    var secondBody: SKPhysicsBody

    if contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask < contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask {
        firstBody = contact.bodyA
        secondBody = contact.bodyB
    } else {
        firstBody = contact.bodyB
        secondBody = contact.bodyA
    }

    if (firstBody.categoryBitMask == BitMask.player) && ( (secondBody.categoryBitMask == BitMask.obstacle) || (secondBody.categoryBitMask == BitMask.frame) )  {

        self.view?.paused = true

        // check if this stops it
        player.physicsBody!.velocity.dx = 0
        player.physicsBody!.velocity.dy = 0

        playerCollided = true

    }
}
```

So this is the code for my touches began function. If the user touches the player block:

```
override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
    let touch = touches.first! as UITouch
    let touchLocation = touch.locationInNode(self)
    let touchedNode = self.nodeAtPoint(touchLocation)
    let name = touchedNode.name

    if name == "player" {

        // first touch
        if playerFirstTouch {
            print("New Game")
            print("Finger is on player block")
            isFingerOnPlayer = true

            NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(0.1, target: self, selector: "printDuration:", userInfo: NSDate(), repeats: true)

            playerFirstTouch = false
            print("\(player.physicsBody!.velocity.dy)")

        } else {
            print("Finger is on player block after game started")
            isFingerOnPlayer = true
            print("\(player.physicsBody!.velocity.dy)")
        }
    }
}

override func touchesMoved(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
    let touch = touches.first! as UITouch
    let touchLocation = touch.locationInNode(self)

    // check if user touched the player block
    if isFingerOnPlayer {
        // get touch location
        if let touch = touches.first {
            let prevTouchLoc = touch.previousLocationInNode(self)
            // calculate new position along x and y
            var newXPos = player.position.x + (touchLocation.x - prevTouchLoc.x)
            var newYPos = player.position.y + (touchLocation.y - prevTouchLoc.y)
            //
            newXPos = max(newXPos, self.player.frame.size.width/2)
            newXPos = min(newXPos, self.size.width - self.player.frame.size.width/2)
            //
            newYPos = max(newYPos, self.player.frame.size.height/2)
            newYPos = min(newYPos, self.size.height - self.player.frame.size.height/2)
            // update player block position
            player.position = CGPointMake(newXPos, newYPos)
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Have the player use precise collision detection, not the scene.  The player is the node that is moving and needs to have it's physics calculations sub-stepped through.  So something like:

```
player.physicsBody!.usesPreciseCollisionDetection = true;
```

You can remove the precise collision detection from the `playScene`, as having it on will just bog down the physics engine.

**Edit**

I'm expanding this to cover how to use the `SKAction` to move the node instead of setting the position.  I'm pretty sure this will work, but let me know.  Check out [the documentation for the moveBy method](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKAction_Ref/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/SKAction/moveTo:duration:) that I'm going to be using.

The first thing that you want to do is delete this line:

```
player.position = CGPointMake(newXPos, newYPos)
```

And we are going to replace it with this line:

```
player.runAction(SKAction.moveTo(CGPointMake(newXPos, newYPos), 0.01))
```

This should move the player to the desired position *really* quickly (I think).

Comment: I just tried tried what you said with no luck I'm afraid.

Comment: Hmm.  Would you mind including how you send the `player` moving?  I'm not seeing anything obviously wrong with the code you have in your question, but there might be something in the swipe code that's doing it (like setting the `x` and `y` values directly).

Comment: I've added the touches began function I use to allow the user to touch and move the player block aroun

Comment: @spigen it seems that you are setting the position manually, this means that the physics body ignores the travel path from a to b.  Instead, try making a really short `SKAction` that moves the `player` from a to b instead.  I *think* that will allow the physics to detect, but I'm not sure.  Let me know!

Comment: When you say I'm setting the position manually do you mean in the touchesMoved function where the new X and Y positions are calculated? How would I implement the SKAction you mentioned? Sorry kind of new to this.

Comment: @spigen check out the edit I made, it should clear up the `SKAction`.

Comment: Interesting effect. I just tried this and had to reduce the duration to something silly like 1e-10 for it to not lag so much. Unfortunately at this point it does what it did before and renders so fast that the player block leaves the frame.